# Spark - match states inside a row of dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my dataframe which I was able to wrangle and extract from multi struct Json files

```
-------------------------------------------
Col1  | Col2|           Col3    |   Col4
-------------------------------------------
A     |  1  |2018-03-28T19:03:39|    Active
-------------------------------------------
A     |  1  |2018-03-28T19:03:40|    Clear
-------------------------------------------
A     |  1  |2018-03-28T19:11:21|    Active
-------------------------------------------
A     |  1  |2018-03-28T20:13:06|    Active
-------------------------------------------
A     |  1  |2018-03-28T20:13:07|    Clear
-------------------------------------------
```

This is what I came up with by grouping by keys

```
A|1|[(2018-03-28T19:03:39,Active),(2018-03-28T19:03:40,Clear),(2018-03-28T19:11:21,Active),(2018-03-28T20:13:06,Active),(2018-03-28T20:13:07,Clear)]
```

and this is my desired output..

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Col1  | Col2|   Active time     |   Clear Time 
--------------------------------------------------------
A     |  1  |2018-03-28T19:03:39|    2018-03-28T19:03:40
--------------------------------------------------------
A     |  1  |2018-03-28T20:13:06|    2018-03-28T20:13:07
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I am kind of stuck at this step and not sure how to proceed further to get the desired output. Any direction is appreciated.

Spark version - 2.1.1
Scala version - 2.11.8

Comment: And why isn't `2018-03-28T19:11:21` in the Active column?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala - records are supposed to come as a pair or active - clear. A missing active/clear means the record was missed in communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use *window function* for the *grouping and ordering* to get the consecutive active and clear time.** Since you are looking *for filtering out the the rows which doesn't have consecutive clear or active status, you would need a filter too.*

so if you have `dataframe` as

```
+----+----+-------------------+------+
|Col1|Col2|Col3               |Col4  |
+----+----+-------------------+------+
|A   |1   |2018-03-28T19:03:39|Active|
|A   |1   |2018-03-28T19:03:40|Clear |
|A   |1   |2018-03-28T19:11:21|Active|
|A   |1   |2018-03-28T20:13:06|Active|
|A   |1   |2018-03-28T20:13:07|Clear |
+----+----+-------------------+------+
```

you can simply do as I explained above

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Col1", "Col2").orderBy("Col3")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("active", lag(struct(col("Col3"), col("Col4")), 1).over(windowSpec))
    .filter(col("active.Col4") === "Active" && col("Col4") === "Clear")
    .select(col("Col1"), col("Col2"), col("active.Col3").as("Active Time"), col("Col3").as("Clear Time"))
  .show(false)
```

and you should get

```
+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|Col1|Col2|Active Time        |Clear Time         |
+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|A   |1   |2018-03-28T19:03:39|2018-03-28T19:03:40|
|A   |1   |2018-03-28T20:13:06|2018-03-28T20:13:07|
+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```